# Should the ambiguous tag [quartz] be blacklisted?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-block-request, ambiguous-tags

[quartz](/questions/tagged/quartz) is ambiguous. It is commonly used for the [Quartz Enterprise Job Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) ([quartz-scheduler](/questions/tagged/quartz-scheduler)) and for some of Apple's Core Graphics technologies ([quartz-2d](/questions/tagged/quartz-2d), etc.)—two topics with absolutely no overlap.

Re-tagging may be difficult as there are several hundred [quartz](/questions/tagged/quartz) questions. Blacklisting would at least stop the number from growing.

Comment: Added to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012